# laravel-echo-server using live redis server

Tags: laravel, echo-server

I have installed laravel-echo-server , and also i installed redis local , the laravel-echo-server when the redis server is local all good ,
i update the laravel-echo-server.json , .env and the config.database to use the live redis server .
but when i run the "laravel-echo-server start" it look to redis locally like :
[image]

any idea how to make it use the live redis server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the probelm , since i want to use live server , i should update the laravel-echo-server.json to update redis database , something like :

"database": "redis",

```
"databaseConfig": {

    "redis": {

        "host": "IP",

        "port": 6379,

        "password":"MY-PASSWORD"

    },
```